# Why my table overlap in a 2 column using a conference LaTeX format?

Tags: tables

I tried to write a table and added in the required usepackage in a conference given LaTeX template.
But cannot figure out how to make the table centre and line.

It output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{icad2020,amsmath,epsfig,times,url}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} %for table multirow
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 

\begin{tabular*}{0.55\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=4]
  S[table-format=4]
  S[table-format=4]
  @{}  
}
\toprule
{\thead{Stimulus \\ Sample}} 
  & {\thead{Class A \\ Sample \\ Sample}}
  & {\thead{Class B \\ Sample \\ Sample}}
  & {\thead{Class C \\ Sample \\ Sample}}\\
\midrule

    Stimulus 7 & A2 & B47 & A28 \\
    Stimulus 8 & A18 & B34 & B33 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{0.55\textwidth}` is forcing it to be more than half the page width so  wider than the column. use `\columnwidth` and add `\extracolsep` to allow the columns to expand or (better usually) just use a normal tabular and don't force the width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Do you mean `\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}`? How to add the `\extacolsep`?

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
  @{}
  l
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=4]
  S[table-format=4]
  S[table-format=4]
  @{}  
}
\toprule`

Comment: Doe using `S` type columns really make sense here? How would you like your entries to be aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your MWE contain package `icad2020` which is not available in public. Please, its add it contents, which influence on page layout, include to your MWE
- omitting `icad2020` your MWE generate one column document in which your problem cannot happen
- in your table you haven't numbers, so other column types can be more appropriate
- used are `S` columns, but you not loaded package, which define it
- you prescribe table width which is bigger than its natural width as well as column width

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twocolumn,
               oneside]{article}
\usepackage{%icad2020,
            amsmath,epsfig,times,url}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} %for table multirow
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{c} @{} }
\toprule
{\thead{Stimulus \\ Sample}}
  & {\thead{Class A \\ Sample \\ Sample}}
  & {\thead{Class B \\ Sample \\ Sample}}
  & {\thead{Class C \\ Sample \\ Sample}}\\
\midrule

    Stimulus 7 & A2 & B47 & A28 \\
    Stimulus 8 & A18 & B34 & B33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One simpler solution using `tabulary`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\tabcolsep0pt 
\tymax.25\dimexpr\linewidth
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}CCCC@{}}\toprule
Stimulus Sample &  
Class A Sample Sample &
Class B Sample Sample &
Class C Sample Sample \\\midrule
Stimulus 7 & A2 & B47 & A28 \\
Stimulus 8 & A18 & B34 & B33 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```